# Call `javaexec` from custom task (`buildSrc`), use transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I’ve written a custom task in Kotlin and located it inside `buildSrc` as recommended. The custom task calls `javaexec`. Something like this:

```
    private fun custom() {
        project.javaexec {
            main = "com.thirdParty.something.Main"
            classpath = ???
            args("...")
        }
    }
```

Two questions:

1. Is `project.javaexec` the best way to call a main method from within a custom task?
2. How can I configure classpath such that `com.thirdParty.something.Main` remains a dependency of the custom task (i.e. `buildSrc/build.kotlin.kts`), and not the main project?